# Fixed Sidebar with TwitterBootstrap 2.3.5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to learn how to implement a fixed sidebar with Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.5.

Here's a snippet of my code

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">  
  <div  class="span4" id="sidebar-left">
            <h2 id="sidebar-head">Hello</h2>
            <p>Look at this stuff, isn't it neat wouldnt you think my collection complete. Wouldn't you think im a girl a girl who has everything.</p>
            <!--sidebar nav-->
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked" id="sidenav">
            <li><a href='#'>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

        <div class="span8" id="main">
            <h1>Some Text Here </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I added this in my CSS but #main and #sidebar-left ended up on top of another:

```
#sidebar-left {
    position:fixed;
}

#main {
    background-color:#39C;
    height: 1500px;
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing with the code. I finally got the solution to my query:

First: I set #sidebar-left to float left. This made sure that the #sidebar-left stays inside the container. The problem though, is that this makes #main stacked with #sidebar-left.

To solve that, I placed #main to .offset4 in order to move the whole div 4 grids to the right.

```
    #sidebar-left {
    position:fixed;
    float: left;
}

<div class="span8 offset4" id="main">
            <h1>Some Text Here </h1>
        </div>
```

Comment: This is incorrect. You don't need bootstrap to place things. Position fixed and float do not work together. I beg you to try and learn positioning instead of throwing in some bootstrap classes and be like, "oh - well this worked." What about in every browser? What about in responsive scenarios? If you remove the `fixed` it will do the same thing. You are just floating a sidebar left and then you offsetting the main area with a margin left. This is bad. You can just float both of them left. Or one of them right. Fixed isn't going to work with anything that doesn't have a mouse.

Answer (score 0):

You poor unfortunate soul, you didn't specify the placement. `position: fixed;` is great ...   but you need `top: 0;` `left: 0;` or something to define it's placement.

Comment: PS - you should test for touch and be sure that the screen/OS can accept position: fixed; -> http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/qKLIo

Comment: @SherriffDerekL: The thing with that is that it messes out with the layout. When I added top:0 left:0, #sidebar-left went out of the container. :(

Comment: When you use fixed positioning, you are positioning based on the browser window. If you don't specify what the position is, then what could you expect to happen? It is likely that all you code is awful. – and that is why it isn't working. Why didn't you include a jsfiddle or some html or a better explanation with a stripped-down use case?

Comment: If it's going out of the container, it's because you are using fixed, and that is the boundary. If you set your container to relative, that becomes a new boundary for element inside of it. Not you can use absolute positioning instead of fixed. But you don't need to. Everything it much more simple than bookstrap makes it.